# React HOC - Generic Container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, functional-programming

**Wizard and WizardPage**

I am trying to build a generic Wizard and WizardPages to be generic a reusable across my app. I think the Wizard component as the one in charge of managing the state, and the WizardPage that is going to work as a wrapper, and will render Back, Cancel and Next buttons. It's suppose that the Next button (maybe the Back too) should dispatch an redux action. This action, could be different depending on the component being wrapped. This is what i have (not complete version):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withWizardLayout from '../../hoc/WithWizardLayout';

class Wizard extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
    };
  }
  nextPage = () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
  };

  previousPage = () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });
  };

  render() {
    const { wizardPages } = this.props;
    const { page } = this.state;
    const wizardItem = wizardPages[page];
    const nextPage = this.nextPage;
    const previousPage = this.previousPage;
    const ComponentWrapped = withWizardLayout(wizardItem.ComponentWrapped, nextPage, previousPage);
    return (
      <ComponentWrapped />
    );
  }
}

 export default Wizard;


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Flex, Box } from 'reflexbox';
import { BlueRoundButton, GreyRoundButton } from '../components/Button';

export default function withWizardLayout(ComponentDependent, nextPageCallBack, previousPageCallback) { 
  class WizardPage extends Component {
    previousPage = () => {
    };
    nextPage = () => {
      this.props.test();
    };   
    render() {
      const { ComponentWrapped, isFirstPage, isLastPage } = ComponentDependent;
        return (
          <Flex column>
            <ComponentWrapped
              isLastPage={isLastPage}
              isFirstPage={isFirstPage}
            >
              <Flex justify='flex-end'>
                <Flex mr='auto' w={0.1}>
                  <GreyRoundButton style={{ fontWeight: '500', position: 'relative', top: '10%' }}>Back</GreyRoundButton>
                </Flex>
                <Flex w={0.08} mr={2} align='center' justify='center' style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  <span>Cancel</span>
                </Flex>
                <Flex w={0.15} justify='center'>
                  <BlueRoundButton onClick={this.nextPage} style={{ position: 'relative', top: '10%', fontWeight: '500' }}>Continue</BlueRoundButton>
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
            </ComponentWrapped>
          </Flex>
        );
      }
  }
```

**CustomersContainer**

```
import { compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CustomerImport from '../components/Settings/CustomerImport';
import { withWizardLayout } from '../hoc/WithWizardLayout';
const mapStateToProps = null;

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    {
        test: () => (dispatch(console.log("hi"))),
    }
);

export default compose(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps))(CustomerImport);
```

**Connected Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  SettingBlock,
  NotifyBlock,
  SuccessMessage,
  ErrorMessage,
  Instructions,
} from './styles';

import ExcelUploader from '../ExcelUploader';

const ProgressBar = styled.div`
  width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: Green;
`;

const ExcelWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
`;

export default class CustomerImport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      progress: 0,
      notify: {
        success: {
          message: '',
          active: false,
        },
        error: {
          message: '',
          active: false,
        },
      },
    };
  }


  render() {
    const { success, error } = this.state.notify;
    const ButtonsWrapper = this.props.children;
    return (
      <div>
        <NotifyBlock>
          <SuccessMessage className={success.active ? 'active' : null}>{success.message}</SuccessMessage>
          <ErrorMessage className={error.active ? 'active' : null}>{error.message}</ErrorMessage>
        </NotifyBlock>
        <SettingBlock>
          <h3>
            Import your customers
          </h3>
          <ProgressBar style={{ width: `${this.state.progress}%` }} />
          <Instructions>
            Select an Excel file containing your customer information.
            Need a template? <a href="">Grab one here.</a>
          </Instructions>
          <ExcelWrapper>
            <ExcelUploader />
          </ExcelWrapper>
          {ButtonsWrapper}
        </SettingBlock>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is how i am supposed to render the Generic Wizard, we can have X wizardPages:

```
const wizardPages = [
  {
    ComponentWrapped: CustomersContainer,
    isFirstPage: false,
    isLastPage: false,
  },
];

<Wizard wizardPages={wizardPages} />
```

The problem with this approach, is that i want on the onClick of the buttons in withWizardLayout:

1) Execute the callback on the Father (that's possible, i am passing as prop the handler)

2) Call the dispatch action received of the container. (i am not able not access the dispatched action, in this case, this.props.test)

How can i refactor this, to think a generic way to handle this? I think another ways to refactor this (having different withWizardLayout functions, but i am having render problems on the console).
Maybe i didn't architect this in the best way.
Help!